# How to include variable when creating button with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm creating buttons dynamically from a javascript for loop by adding this code.

```
var container = document.getElementById('myList');
var new_element = document.createElement('li');
new_element.innerHTML = '<button type="button" id="">label</button>';
```

I need to add elements from an array to both the buttons id and label. Like this for example;

```
arrMarkers[i].title
```

**How can I enclose these array values in the string that creates the button?**

Comment: whats the issue? its a usual concate `'<button type="button" id="'+arrMarkers[i].title+'">label</button>';`

Comment: Did you get button over there...?? As far i know , you wouldn't get any button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newElement.innerHTML = '<button type="button" id="' + arrMarkers[i].id + '">' + arrMarkers[i].title + '</button>';
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you are looking for string concatenation:

```
new_element.innerHTML = '<button type="button" id="' + arrMarkers[i].id + '">' + arrMarkers[i].title + '</button>';
```

Comment: `:D` Who didn't like string concatenation?

Comment: can't get why this answer is downvoted. can someone explain this to me?

Comment: may be its too simple for Vision to Answer...:). Why not upvote if it deserve one. and make the downvote meaningless

Comment: @RabNawaz Ha! Sorry for easy answer `:)` You are very welcome to even the overall score `;)`